# A generic function to store Eigen matrix in a binary file

Tags: c++, abstract-class, eigen, eigen3

I know that the following code can be used to write the data of an Eigen Matrix  with datatype as `double` to a binary file.

```
template<class  T> 
void WriteEigenMatrix(const Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>& m, const char* fileName)
{
    std::ofstream outFile(fileName, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    outFile.write(m.data(), m.rows()*m.cols());
    outFile.close();`
}
```

How can I generalize this function to accept other Eigen data types like `Eigen::Vector` and `Eigen::Array` as inputs?
If I use `Eigen::EigenBase`, I know that the function will accept all such data types. However, the problem is that I can no longer use `m.data()`, as it is not defined in the base class.
Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: `template<class  T> void WriteEigen(const T& m, const char* fileName) { /* same code */ }`?

Comment: Be very careful when doing binary serialization. You kind of assume that the data will be read again by the same program using the exact same compiler and compiler settings. If you want your code to be portable you might need to use a serialization library instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allow only "Dense" objects, you can to it as follows:

```
template<class Derived>
void WriteEigen(const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& dense, const char* fileName) {
    std::ofstream outFile(fileName, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(dense.derived().data()), dense.rows() * dense.cols());
    outFile.close();
}
```

All dense Matrices (including vector & array) inherit from `DenseBase`, calling `derived` on `DenseBase` will give you back the concrete matrix type.

Or use any Base you like.

After comments from @chtz and @Homer512 this version uses `PlainObjectBase` and `reshaped` in combination with STL algorithm to write to the file, avoiding `reinterpret_cast` to `char*` and the possible failure in case `innerStride() != 1`.

```
template<class Derived>
void WriteEigen(const Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>& dense, std::string_view fileName) {
    std::ofstream outFile(fileName, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    const auto& reshaped = dense.reshaped();
    std::copy(reshaped.begin(), reshaped.end(), std::ostream_iterator<typename Derived::Scalar>(outFile));
}
```

`reshaped()` allows to iterate over all entries in an STL manner [see example](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSTL.html), which will take care of all possible strides. C++20 ranges allows for the nicer

```
std::ranges::copy(reshaped, std::ostream_iterator<typename Derived::Scalar>(outFile));
```

Using `std::ostream_iterator` allows to use `std::(ranges::)copy` instead of `ostream::write()` which operates on bytes. To get the underlying data type of the Eigen object, `Dense::Scalar` can be used.

Comment: [`PlainObjectBase`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html) might be a slightly better choice -- this avoids that `Map` objects get stored. OTOH, OP may want to allow that as well. Also you don't need the `.derived()` for `PlainObjectBase`.

Comment: To elaborate, the existing code will fail silently when you pass an object with an [`outerStride`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseCoeffsBase_3_01Derived_00_01DirectAccessors_01_4.html#ad88c60c4a2356be2c436f3264dd20b55) that differs from its row number (for column-major), e.g. `matrix.topRows(N)` or `innerStride() != 1`, e.g. `matrix.row(i)`. `PlainObjectBase` avoids this but may be overly restrictive. Alternatively put in a few assertions or do fallbacks that save column-by-column (for outer stride) or scalar by scalar (for inner stride)